# Ubuntu 16.04 takes a long time for login to desktop

Tags: 16.04, login

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 with clean partitions multiple times but every time I reinstalled it boots to the login prompt, then when I log in it seems to do nothing for about 40 seconds before the desktop appears. The system appears normal until I select **About this Computer** or click on **System Settings** when again, nothing happens for about 40 seconds (in fact you can't do anything until this time is up) and then all is normal again.

There is no delay, if I suspend and the system returns almost instantly from suspend.

The installation is on a HP Compaq 2510p with a ATA KingSpec KSD-ZF1 30Gb hard drive and 2 GB RAM. This had been running with no problems until an update corrupted the system, after which a fresh install always resulted in the above symptoms.

Answer (score 2):

run this command and open the file `bootup-01.svg` in your home directory to see an analyze of yoour system's boot, it may help.

```
systemd-analyze plot > bootup-01.svg
```

And/Or run `systemd-analyze blame` to see what's taking its time on boot.

Comment: Would these commands help with solving long login times ?

Comment: @SorenA As I said, they may help to find what did cause the long boot and login time. Yes.

Comment: This answer is to how to find which service takes longer time in initialization...it is missing a finish!